# Storybook/React Unable to index introduction.stories.mdx

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have an old project that am trying to view and modify its component through the component explorer but everytime i try to run with

```
yarn storybook
```

it opens up on browser with no components or modules showing up and with this error

```
ERROR in ./src/stories/Introduction.stories.mdx Module build failed (from 
./node_modules/@storybook/mdx2-csf/loader.js): Could not parse expression with acorn: 
Unterminated template @ ./src/ lazy ^\.\/.*$ include: (?:\/src(?:\/(?%21\.)(?:(?:(? 
%21(?:^%7C\/)\.).)*?)\/%7C\/%7C$)(?%21\.)(?=.)[^/]*?\.mdx)$ chunkName: [request] 
 namespace object ./stories/Introduction.stories.mdx @ ./storybook-stories.js 10:11- 
14:5 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 6:0-50 25:21-29 28:2-31:4 28:58-31:3 30:31-39
```

Additional information
another error is shown up under that one is

```
preview compiled with 1 error => Failed to build the preview 99% end closing watch 
compilationWARN Force closed preview build SB_BUILDER-WEBPACK5_0003 
(WebpackCompilationError): There were problems when compiling your code with Webpack. 
Run Storybook with --debug-webpack for more information. at starter 
(./node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/index.js:1:9660) at starter.next 
(<anonymous>) at Module.start (./node_modules/@storybook/builder- 
webpack5/dist/index.js:1:11692) at process.processTicksAndRejections 
(node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Comment: Can you provide information about your environment (e.g. nodejs, yarn versions)?

Сan you also provide dependency information from the package.json file?

The problem may be due to the installation of incompatible packages. Have you tried installing exact versions of packages, for example via npm ci?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to the compilation of your MDX files using the `@storybook/mdx2-csf/loader` during the Storybook build process.

### 1. Check MDX file syntax:

Ensure that your `Introduction.stories.mdx` file has correct syntax. Look for any unclosed templates or other syntax errors.

### 2. Update dependencies:

Make sure that your dependencies, especially Storybook-related packages, are up to date. Use this to update,

```bash
yarn upgrade --latest
```

### 3. Check Storybook configuration:

Verify that your Storybook configuration is set up correctly. Ensure that you have the necessary addons, loaders, and plugins configured.

### 4. Debug webpack:

Run Storybook with the `--debug-webpack` flag to get more detailed information about the webpack build process. This might help you identify the specific issue causing the compilation error.

```bash
yarn storybook --debug-webpack
```

After trying these steps, if the issue persists, you may need to provide more details about your project structure, webpack configuration, and the content of your MDX files for a more accurate diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a compatibility issue with Webpack and your "old project".

Storybook use Webpack **5**, and in addition you are using the **lazyCompilation**, which is experimental.

I think this might be your exact issue, but without the content of your MDX I won't be able to tell more : https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/issues/1945

Otherwise, tweaking Webpack configuration might help you to resolve your issue : https://storybook.js.org/docs/builders/webpack

And I would advise you to simply follow the instruction in the error to have more information (and maybe share it here if it doesn't help you)

```
Run Storybook with --debug-webpack for more information
```